# Foreign key in MVC 3 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a small MVC application. In it I have two tables:

- movieLanguage - LanguageID (primary key) , Language
- Movie - MovieID (primary key) , LanguageID(Fkey) , moviename etc ..

When I try to update movie table:

```
var movie = movEntity.Movies.Single(a => a.MovieID == id);
TryUpdateModel(movie);
movEntity.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I'm getting an error:

> The property 'LanguageID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Can you show us your models of that tables?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to copy over the `LanguageID` property, and that's not possible since it's used to identify the row in the database table.

These kind of errors can be avoided by using a proper view model.

Read my following blog post: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

Comment: @json: The ASP.NET MVC website is an excellent resource: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview Look at the video and getting started sections.

Comment: I changed my edit method as follows .Now i m not getting nay error but its not updating                               [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Movies mov)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateModel(mov);
                movEntity.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

As jqauffin said, you may refer to that video and available tutorials there.
For your problem, you are trying to overwrite the "key" value and that is why the error.

You could be doing either of the following.

1. The identity column is not auto-incremented but still a Primary Key and you are trying to insert another row with the same PK which is not allowed
2. The identity column is auto incremented and you are trying to insert/update the same row for the second time.

Try creating a new instance of the required table by "new" operator and then insert.  So that each row is considered as a new record.

Please refer this blog for sample code snippet:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs

Happy learning

Comment: But I am trying to update Movie  table which has a foreign key refernce to movieLanguage .